# Can the Samsung Galaxy Tab be used as a wifi-hotspot?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, wifi-tethering, wifi-hotspot

Is it possible to use the Samsung Galaxy Tab as a wifi-hotspot so that non-3G iPads can use the Samsungs connection to the phone network?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Galaxy Tab comes with Android version 2.2 (Froyo), this version of the Android OS comes with the ability to work as a WiFi hotspot for up to 5 devices built in. This lets you share your Tab's 3G connection out to other devices over Wifi.

I've tethered wifi only devices like my Kindle 3, and a wifi Skype phone to my Galaxy S's wireless hotspot in this way and connected them to the internet with no problem, so I can't see any reason you'd have trouble doing that between a 3G Galaxy Tab and a Wifi iPad.

(it is possible for your phone company to block this facility, to date I think [Verizon in the US are the only company to block it](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/08/verizon-droid-android-update/))

Comment: end of first paragraph -- I think you mean "WiFi" not "3G"

Comment: @matt well spotted, glad someone's proof reading!

Comment: I think Sprint charges an extra $20-$30/month for the WiFi hotspot feature. At least on the HTC/EVO that's what it is. I got it on the HTC/EVO so it will provide internet for any future Galaxy or tablet I might buy.

Comment: @Neal if there's one thing I'm constantly reminded of, it's to never be surprised by the greed of phone networks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

**Settings >  Wireless and Network > Mobile AP**

This feature is built by Samsung, and different from the tethering feature that comes with Android 2.2 (Froyo). Using this one you can turn your Tab as a password-protected hotspot

Comment: is it possible that the Mobile AP could be deleted off of the phone because its not under Settings > Wireless and Network > Mobile AP i have the Samsung Galaxay S though a southern provider called Cellular South down here in MS.

Comment: @user3176 On 2.3 the feature is another level down under Settings > Wireless and Network > Tethering > Mobile AP. Also if you bought the device through your service provider then it is possible that they may have disabled that feature. Some networks (especially in the US it seems) disable the tethering features on their devices.