# Share WIFI to Computer?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-tab, internet, wifi-hotspot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the Samsung Galaxy Tab be used as a wifi-hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/can-the-samsung-galaxy-tab-be-used-as-a-wifi-hotspot)

Is their a way I can share the WiFi on my Galaxy Tab on my PC without having a landline internet access already available? My mom and I are really curious because it's hard to do computer projects when you can't save it to a folder that is personal when you have little siblings, please HELP! (:

Comment: The other question should have what you need, in particular Louis' answer.  Let us know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* your question is a duplicate, it's a bit hard to understand given how it's worded.  Check out [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/can-the-samsung-galaxy-tab-be-used-as-a-wifi-hotspot).